# How to find documents with recurring dates

Tags: solr

I've been tasked with using Solr to search for appointments by date. This needs to handle appointments that have a recurring schedule (e.g., occurs every Wednesday at 9:30). The only solution I've come up with so far is to use a multi-value date (or date range) field and calculate all of the occurrence dates. This is problematic when there is no end date, but it is acceptable to limit the number of dates recorded. Is there any other way to do this?

We are currently using Solr 6.5.1 if that matters.

Comment: What would your query be? A range or an exact date?

Comment: @MatsLindh We will be querying using a range.